# How to get origial value in jquery crop image

Tags: php, jquery

I downloaded one jquery crop image module it is working fine,actually i want now that original image value,from this code i got only for cropped image value,when i upload one image means i want store that image in without crop,actually i don't know how to get that value in this code reference URL http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/v1.0.0/

```
$(function () {
'use strict';
var console = window.console || { log: function () {} };
var $body = $('body');


// Tooltip
// $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
// $.fn.tooltip.noConflict();
// $body.tooltip();


// Demo
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

(function () {
var $image = $('.img-container > img');
console.log($image);
var $actions = $('.docs-actions');
var $download = $('#download');
//console.log($download);
var $dataX = $('#dataX');
var $dataY = $('#dataY');
var $dataHeight = $('#dataHeight');
var $dataWidth = $('#dataWidth');
var $dataRotate = $('#dataRotate');
var $dataScaleX = $('#dataScaleX');
var $dataScaleY = $('#dataScaleY');
var options = {
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      preview: '.img-preview',
      crop: function (e) {
        $dataX.val(Math.round(e.x));
        $dataY.val(Math.round(e.y));
        $dataHeight.val(Math.round(e.height));
        $dataWidth.val(Math.round(e.width));
        $dataRotate.val(e.rotate);
        $dataScaleX.val(e.scaleX);
        $dataScaleY.val(e.scaleY);
      }
    };
$image.on({
  'build.cropper': function (e) {
    //console.log(e.type);
  },
  'built.cropper': function (e) {
    //console.log(e.type);
  },
  'cropstart.cropper': function (e) {
    //console.log(e.type, e.action);
  },
  'cropmove.cropper': function (e) {
    //console.log(e.type, e.action);
  },
  'cropend.cropper': function (e) {
    //console.log(e.type, e.action);
  },
  'crop.cropper': function (e) {
   // console.log(e.type, e.x, e.y, e.width, e.height, e.rotate, e.scaleX, e.scaleY);
  },
  'zoom.cropper': function (e) {
    console.log(e.type, e.ratio);
  }
}).cropper(options);


// Methods
$actions.on('click', '[data-method]', function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var data = $this.data();
  var $target;
  var result;

  if ($this.prop('disabled') || $this.hasClass('disabled')) {
    return;
  }

  if ($image.data('cropper') && data.method) {
    data = $.extend({}, data); // Clone a new one

    if (typeof data.target !== 'undefined') {
      $target = $(data.target);

      if (typeof data.option === 'undefined') {
        try {
          data.option = JSON.parse($target.val());
        } catch (e) {
        //console.log(e.message);

        }
      }
    }

    result = $image.cropper(data.method, data.option, data.secondOption);

    if (data.flip === 'horizontal') {
      $(this).data('option', -data.option);
    }

    if (data.flip === 'vertical') {
      $(this).data('secondOption', -data.secondOption);
    }

    if (data.method === 'getCroppedCanvas' && result) {
      $('#getCroppedCanvasModal').modal().find('.modal-body').html(result);

      if (!$download.hasClass('disabled')) {
        $download.attr('href', result.toDataURL());
        console.log(result.toDataURL());//data:base64 ans

            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('#crop').click(function(){
                //console.log('ok');
                $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url: "crop_image_insert.php",
                        data: ({'crop': result.toDataURL()}),
                        success:function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                            if(data == 'SUCCESS'){
                            window.location.assign('php/timeline.php?id=<?php echo $ssmid;?>'); 
                            }
                        },
                        error:function(error){
                            alert('n');
                        }
                    }); 
                 });
              });
         }

    }
    if ($.isPlainObject(result) && $target) {
      try {
        $target.val(JSON.stringify(result));
      } catch (e) {

      }
    }

  }
});


// Keyboard
$body.on('keydown', function (e) {

  if (!$image.data('cropper') || this.scrollTop > 300) {
    return;
  }

  switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
      e.preventDefault();
      $image.cropper('move', -1, 0);
      break;

    case 38:
      e.preventDefault();
      $image.cropper('move', 0, -1);
      break;

    case 39:
      e.preventDefault();
      $image.cropper('move', 1, 0);
      break;

    case 40:
      e.preventDefault();
      $image.cropper('move', 0, 1);
      break;
  }

});


// Import image
var $inputImage = $('#inputImage');
var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var blobURL;

if (URL) {
  $inputImage.change(function () {
    var files = this.files;
    var file;

    if (!$image.data('cropper')) {
      return;
    }

    if (files && files.length) {
      file = files[0];

      if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
        blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        $image.one('built.cropper', function () {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL); // Revoke when load complete
        }).cropper('reset').cropper('replace', blobURL);
        $inputImage.val('');

      } else {
        $body.tooltip('Please choose an image file.', 'warning');
      }
      console.log($inputImage.val(''));
    }
  });
} else {
  $inputImage.prop('disabled', true).parent().addClass('disabled');
}
}());

});
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log`  `$dataHeight` and  `$dataWidth` ?

Comment: Now i tried i got console.log($dataHeight); //[context: document, selector: "#dataHeight"]

Comment: what you are getting with console.log( $image ) ?

Comment: console.log( $image ) // [img, prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".img-container > img"]

Comment: can you try `console.log( $image.width() );` ?

Comment: console.log( $image.width() ) //848

Comment: Reference link http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/v1.0.0/

Comment: what 848 is ? is the width of image ?

Comment: there is a button  "Get image data" that has the original image height and width stored as `{"naturalWidth":1280,"naturalHeight":720,..}` why you are not using the same ??

Comment: come down download link will be there ,i downloaded inside this code will there so i am using this code

Comment: give ur mail id will send my file,then u come to know

Comment: ok, give your email id, I will send you a blank email .

Comment: mani5524idea@gmail.com